# How can i disable module manually in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1

I'd like to know if its possible to manually disable a module by changing some code like in Magento 1.
I know the SSH way.

Comment: Go to `app/etc/config.php` and disable a module by changing it's value from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 12):

You can always use CLI command for managing modules.

Disable module:

```
$ bin/magento module:disable Vendor_ModuleName
```

Enable module:

```
  $ bin/magento module:enable Vendor_ModuleName
```

And you can check status of all modules:

```
$ bin/magento module:status
```

It is useful to build a habit of controlling your installation via bin/magento. Also it will help to avoid any new features introduced for module commands.

Answer (score 11):

In order ***disable a module*** manually, *you need to* do some changes at `app/etc/config.php`

In this file, magento save value ***flag value 0 or 1 of each module***.

- *1 means Modules is enabled*
- *0 Means Modules is disabled*

As , you want to disable the module then you need **change it value to  0**.

Then go to var folder and clear *`cache,page_cache`* folder.

### Example

Suppose.your config.php look like

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array 
.......
    'Magento_CheckoutAgreements' => 1,
    'Magento_Payment' => 1,
    'Magento_SampleData' => 1,
    'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite' => 1,
    'Magento_Config' => 1,
    'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport' => 1,
    'Magento_Downloadable' => 1,
    'Magento_Wishlist' => 1,
.....
  ),
);
```

Then you want to disable then you need  make  `'Magento_CheckoutAgreements' => 1,`  to `'Magento_CheckoutAgreements' => 0`,